# Want to delete an item from a list taken from JSON

Tags: c#, json, list, linq

I want to to be able to pass in the name of the item I want to delete from the list.
But when I debug out the variable that comes through, it gives me:

```
Car Name: Happy Car
```

What Do I need to do to eliminate the extra letters?
Do I need to use `CharToTrim'?
Thanks for the help in advance...

```
if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/JSON/dbindex.json"))
{
    //Load in JSON file
    string dbindex = File.ReadAllText (Application.persistentDataPath + "/JSON/dbindex.json");
    //Load file in as an array
    DatabaseIndex[] _tempLoadIndexList = JsonHelper.FromJson<DatabaseIndex> (dbindex);
    //Convert to List
    DBIndexList = _tempLoadIndexList.OfType<DatabaseIndex>().ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < DBIndexList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (DBIndexList[i].DatabaseName == dbname)
            {
                DBIndexList.Remove(DBIndexList[i]);
            }

    }
```

If I replace dbname in the for loop with the text "Happy Car" it works. When I use my variable in there, it does not.

Comment: Your question and your code together aren't making much sense.

Comment: I'm also having trouble understanding the relationship between your question and the code.  They don't look at all related.

Comment: Are you saying your JSON is not parsing correctly? So basically you have `Car Name: 'Happy Car'` in your JSON and you're getting the whole thing back?
Edit: Please share the contents of dbindex.json

Comment: {"CarDatabases":[{"DatabaseName":"Happy Car"},{"DatabaseName":"Fun Car"},{"DatabaseName":"Sad Car"},{"DatabaseName":"Sport Car"},{"DatabaseName":"Exotic Car"}]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (DBIndexList[i].DatabaseName == dbname.Replace("Car Name: ", string.Empty))
{
   DBIndexList.Remove(DBIndexList[i]);
}
```

Another way (case insensitive also)

```
string dbNameTrimmed = dbname.TrimStart("Car Name: ".ToCharArray());
if(DBIndexList[i].DatabaseName.Equals(dbNameTrimmed, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
   DBIndexList.Remove(DBIndexList[i]);
}
```